# Loop structure for histogram

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, histogram

I'm trying to write a Java program that generates a histogram of asterisks for each occurrence of a value in an array.

If the elements are, respectively, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 the output should have an asterisk for each occurrence. For example,

```
0:*
1:*
2:*
3:*
4:*
5:*
6:*
7:*
8:*
9:*
```

However, my output is

```
0:**********
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:
6:
7:
8:
9:
```

The following code below is my own.

```
public static void drawHistogram(double[] array) {

    String count = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] < 1) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 1 && array[i] < 2) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 3) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 3 && array[i] < 4) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 4 && array[i] < 5) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 5 && array[i] < 6) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 6 && array[i] < 7) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 8) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 9) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 9 && array[i] < 10) {
            count += "*";
        } else if (array[i] >= 10 && array[i] < 11) {
            count += "*";
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + count);
        count = "";
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like you're only keeping one count.  How do you expect to keep track of multiple values with just one count?

Comment: I would suggest adding a new array of Strings called countStrings[] where element 0 keeps track of the count of values less than 1, element 1 keeps track of the count of values less than 2 and so on.  In the code of each `if` condition, you'd then append an asterisk to the appropriate element in the array.  For example, if `array[i] >= 3 && array[i] < 4`, you would execute the statement `countStrings[3] += "*";`

Comment: You could simplify the code even further by using the `Math.floor` function and get rid of all the if-then-else statements.

Comment: Something like `countStrings[Math.floor(array[i])) += "*";`

Comment: `Math.floor` just converts a double to the next smallest integer.  So `Math.floor(3.5)` would be 3.

Comment: I originally thought I could reset the string count back to "" so it would first print and then be reset before re-entering the loop. I ended up finishing the problem by initializing a string counter variable for each number 0-10 and adding a * to each respective counter. However, your solution is much more simple, I appreciate your help.  --Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `(int) Math.floor(array[i])` to choose the bracket into which to put the double value, thus getting rid of the multiple if-then-else statements. I've also used StringBuilder instead of String to make the repeated concatenation of asterisks a little more efficient.

```
public static void drawHistogram(double[] array) {

    StringBuilder histoGram[] = new StringBuilder[11];
    for (int i = 0; i < histoGram.length; i++) {
        histoGram[i] = new StringBuilder();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int bracket = (int) Math.floor(array[i]);
        if (bracket >= 0 && bracket < histoGram.length) {
            histoGram[bracket].append("*");
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        System.out.format("%02d: %s\n", j, histoGram[j].toString());
    }
}
```

Test `main` method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double[] testValues = new double[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        testValues[i] = Math.random() * 11.0;
    }
    drawHistogram(testValues);
}
```

Sample output:

```
00: *******
01: ********
02: ***********
03: ************
04: ********
05: **********
06: *******
07: ********
08: **********
09: ************
10: *******
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void drawHistogram(double[] array) {

        String count[] = new String[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] < 1) {
                count[0] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 1 && array[i] < 2) {
                count[1] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 3) {
                count[2] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 3 && array[i] < 4) {
                count[3] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 4 && array[i] < 5) {
                count[4] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 5 && array[i] < 6) {
                count[5] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 6 && array[i] < 7) {
                count[6] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 8) {
                count[7] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 2 && array[i] < 9) {
                count[8] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 9 && array[i] < 10) {
                count[9] = "*";
            } else if (array[i] >= 10 && array[i] < 11) {
                count[10] = "*";
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + count[j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using only a single variable to count up the occurrences of numbers in this method. This results in you program showing that 0 has nine occurrences and the rest of the numbers have 0 occurrences. I agree with the user David Choweller in the comments, who suggested that you could use an array to solve this problem. However, another solution might be a HashMap, where you store the number as the key, and the string that you want to print out as the value. Then, you can use the loop through the numbers at the end as you do currently, and print out the values associated with them.

Comment: I just wanted to note that the array solution might be faster and more efficient, but I wanted to share the solution that first came to my mind when I saw this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @UnknowableIneffible

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a Java Hasmap :**

```
int myArray[] = new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1};
public static void main (String args[]) {
  HashMap<Integer, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
  hash.put(5, "");
  hash.put(4, "");
  hash.put(3, "");
  hash.put(2, "");
  hash.put(1, "");
  
  for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    hash.put(new Integer(myArray[i]), hash.get(myArray[i])+"*");
  }
  
  for(Integer key: hash.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key+": "+ hash.get(key));
  }
}
```